# Stream Buffer for voice chat / voIP?

Tags: android, stream, udp, buffer, rtp

I understand stream `buffer` is useful for IO in general.

I'd like to ask how `buffer` should be used in realtime voIP applications, 
such as stream in (Android) MediaRecorder output -> LocalSocket ->UDP / RTP

To me, it looks like there's no space for buffer any stream.

Am I correct? or Do I miss something important?

How about device resource efficiency(CPU & Buttery) when not to use buffer in this case?

**pseudocode**

```
//UNIX type localSocket Server to receive stream from mediaRecorder
server = new LocalServerSocket(SOCKET_ADDRESS);

// local socket between mediaRecorder and localSocket Server
 sender = new LocalSocket();
 sender.connect(new LocalSocketAddress(SOCKET_ADDRESS));
//mediaRecorder
 mRecorder = new MediaRecorder(); 
 //.....................
 //sender.getFileDescriptor() is set as the vitual Outputfile
 mRecorder.setOutputFile(sender.getFileDescriptor());
 mRecorder.prepare();
 mRecorder.start();

//localSocket Server accept the stream to receiver
receiver = server.accept();

int val;
byte[] buf;
DatagramPacket packet;
ds = new DatagramSocket(localPort);

while (localServerLoop)
{ 
    //receiver stream is read to (int)val
    val = receiver.getInputStream().read();  
    //======localServer to remoteUDP======================     
    // (int)val to (byte)buf
    buf = toBytes(val);
    //  byte  to packet
    packet = new DatagramPacket(buf, buf.length,
            InetAddress.getByName(remoteHost), remotePort);
    //send to remoteHost
    ds.send(packet);
    //=========================
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are reading a single byte from the stream, so there is nothing to buffer really. Use one of the `read()` methods that take a byte array, that will be your buffer. You can also wrap with `BufferedInputStream`, etc. You might want to read up on how stream work in Java in general, this is not Android specific.

See [http://developer.android.com/reference/java/io/InputStream.html#read(byte[])](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/io/InputStream.html#read%28byte%5B%5D%29)

Comment: Thanks for your very informative answer. I will investigate these.